# pass parameters using variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a simple syntax question.

I declare a variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var id_1= '<?php echo $id; ?>';
    </script>
```

And then in a externally loaded js file im trying to call a function using the variable (the external js file is loaded after the ^^ variable declaration:

```
 loadComments(id_1);
```

The id_1 is being passed literally as 'id_1', not recognizing it should be a variable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what value does the `$id` hold in php.. add an `alert(id_1);` right after assigning the variable... what does it alert ?

Comment: @gaby 2 .. the php isnt the problem

Comment: Your code should be fine as it stands. Probably it's some kind of scope problem. What is the error message?

Comment: can you post the `loadComments` code ? and do you get an error or just wrong results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var id_1 = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
```

Will echo something like this:

```
var id_1 = '10';
```

Which is treated as a string in JavaScript. You want to do this instead, so that you assign a number to `id_1`:

```
var id_1 = <?php echo $id; ?>;
```

This will print out something like this:

```
var id_1 = 10;
```

Comment: Alternatively, keep the quotes and run something like parseInt() in the variable.

Comment: @Christoph That would work, but there's no need to do so; if you can assign an integer verbatim, why go through the hassle of casting a string to an integer?

Comment: For example when `$id;` can be more then just a number? Then it would throw an error, while keeping the quotes, parsing it and checking for a number would not.

Comment: If it is, but you want to assign a number to a JS variable and you have full control over the script that generates `$id`, then you're doing something wrong if you assign `20foo` to `id_1`.

Comment: Well, I understand your point, but still these were only implications made from your side and not confirmed by the OP;)

Comment: Let it be a GUID which is not a valid number due to the `xxxx-xxxx` format or maybe hex or octal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The php code is recognized only by a .php file.

Put your code in a .php file and run it on you local server

Comment: That isnt the problem, the php code is being processed just fine. What the browser sees is `var id_q = '2'`